# unable to boot openvms on as1200

Tags: openvms

When trying to boot openvms 8.3 from CD on a alphaserver 1200 from the SRM console I get this output, nothing else happens.

```
P00>>>boot dka100
(boot dka100.1.0.1.1)
block 0 of dka100.1.0.1.1 is a valid boot block
reading 15 blocks from dka100.1.0.1.1
bootstrap code read in
Building FRU table
base = 200000, image_start = 0, image_bytes = 1e00
initializing HWRPB at 2000
initializing page table at 1f2000
initializing machine state
setting affinity to the primary CPU
jumping to bootstrap code

halted CPU 0

halt code = 5
HALT instruction executed
PC = 20000000        
P00>>>
```

SRM options:

```
boot_osflags ""
os_type openvms
```

SRM 'show dev'

```
P00>>>show dev
polling ncr0 (NCR 53C810) slot 1, bus 0 PCI, hose 1 �  SCSI Bus ID 7
dka0.0.0.1.1       DKA0                     HP DVD-ROM 6x/32x R  1.07
polling ncr1 (NCR 53C875) slot 0, bus 2 PCI, hose 1   SCSI Bus ID 7
dkb0.0.0.2000.1    DKB0                     RZ2DA-LA  N1H1
dkb100.1.0.2000.1  DKB100                   RZ2DA-LA  N1H1
dkb200.2.0.2000.1  DKB200                   RZ2DA-LA  N1H1
dkb300.3.0.2000.1  DKB300                   RZ2DA-LA  N1H1
dkb400.4.0.2000.1  DKB400                   RZ2DA-LA  N1H1
dkb500.5.0.2000.1  DKB500                   RZ2DA-LA  N1H1
dkb600.6.0.2000.1  DKB600                   RZ1DF-CB  0372
```

This output is from when I try to boot openvms 7.3:

```
(boot dka0.0.0.1.1 -flags 0,0)
block 0 of dka0.0.0.1.1 is a valid boot block
reading 936 blocks from dka0.0.0.1.1
bootstrap code read in
Building FRU table
base = 200000, image_start = 0, image_bytes = 75000
initializing HWRPB at 2000
initializing page table at 1f2000
initializing machine state
setting affinity to the primary CPU
jumping to bootstrap code

*************************************************************
* Exception taken before exception handler has been loaded! *
* Unable to take crash dump!                                *
*************************************************************

Access control violation through vector 00000080

R00: 00000000 00000000    R01: 00000000 20051BF8    R02: 00000000 200011F8
R03: 00000080 200513C0    R04: 00000000 2010642A    R05: 00000000 00000000
R06: 00000000 200052D4    R07: 00000000 0000FFFF    R08: 00000000 00000000
R09: 00000000 00000001    R10: 00000000 00000001    R11: 00000000 2004EE60
R12: 00000000 00000001    R13: 00000000 00000001    R14: 00000000 00000000
R15: 00000000 80000000    R16: 00000000 200BBCF0    R17: 00000000 00006428
R18: 00000000 20100006    R19: 00000000 00000000    R20: 00000000 00000000
R21: 00000000 00006428    R22: 442E4558 45535953    R23: 00000000 200BBCF8
R24: 00000000 0000000A    R25: 00000000 200BBCC8    R26: 00000000 200052D4
R27: 00000000 00000000    R28: 442E4558 45535953    R29: 00000000 200BBC70

R30: 200BBC00:   00000000 20057EA0    Saved R02
     200BBC08:   00000000 2010642A    Saved R03
     200BBC10:   00000000 200C3800    Saved R04
     200BBC18:   00000000 200C3600    Saved R05
     200BBC20:   00000000 00000000    Saved R06
     200BBC28:   00000000 0000FFFF    Saved R07
     200BBC30:   00000000 200053A8    Exception PC
     200BBC38:   30000000 00001F00    Exception PS


halted CPU 0

halt code = 5
HALT instruction executed
PC = 20001328        
warning -- HWRPB is invalid
P00>>>
```

What to do? Help is appreciated.

Comment: Now that's odd, it's [officially supported](http://h71000.www7.hp.com/openvms/integrity/faqs.html#5) .. no other output?

Comment: No, but I suspect that it might be a hardware problem, I know the CD-ROM has been replaced and might not be setup correct. I don't know how to check that thou. See 'show dev' output from SRM.

Comment: `Exception taken before exception handler has been loaded!`, Yup, I'm pretty sure you've got a wonky card or cable.

Comment: @enzotib I initially thought the same thing. Then I started an argument in my head to the tune of "Is VMS unix-like enough to qualify here?", then I gave up and had a beer with Reddit. VMS (open or not) is a _time sharing_ OS with a _vmm_, which could also describe multics, which would probably be welcomed here if someone got it up and running. Good question for meta, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hardware issue. It can be the motherboard,the CPU socket or the CPU itself.
I just realized it's 3 years old question xD